# Exception ao gerar Controller com Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Em minha aplicação utilizando **Asp.net mvc**, com **Entity Framework 6**, com **Mysql**, ao tentar adicionar os *Controllers*, com *Views*, utilizando *EF*, tenho o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Configurações do meu **web.config**:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=MeuServer;user id=MeuUsuario;password=******;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=MeuDatabase&quot;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>

  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Como posso resolver este problema? 
Obrigado.

**NOTA**

Ao tentar  criar um *controller* sem utilizar *EF*, e adicionar as *Views* manualmente, utilizando template ocorre o mesmo erro.

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas experimente comentar esta linha: `<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>`

Comment: Já havia tentado isso, e não resolveu, reparei que o erro ocorre durante o scaffolding.

Comment: Bom, você tem como colocar esse projeto num controle de versão pra eu dar uma olhada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gerando a partir do scaffolding tenta retirar ultima parte que seleciona a conexão Data Conext e faça o scaffolding a partir de uma model não diretamente da entidade.